# list of date formats supported by rich:calender

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I searched for the list of date formats supported by Rich:Calender in google.
FMDAY,DD MONTH YYYY and DD MON YYYY date formats when selected are not working as expected in Rich:Calender. Can someone help to find the equivalent date formats for FMDAY,DD MONTH YYYY and DD MON YYYY date formats for Rich:Calender or any source from where i can get the list of supported date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It are just standard Java [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns. You can find a table in its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation        Examples
------  ----------------------  ------------------  -----------------------------
G       Era designator          Text                AD
y       Year                    Year                1996; 96
M       Month in year           Month               July; Jul; 07
w       Week in year            Number              27
W       Week in month           Number              2
D       Day in year             Number              189
d       Day in month            Number              10
F       Day of week in month    Number              2
E       Day in week             Text                Tuesday; Tue
a       Am/pm marker            Text                PM
H       Hour in day (0-23)      Number              0
k       Hour in day (1-24)      Number              24
K       Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number              0
h       Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number              12
m       Minute in hour          Number              30
s       Second in minute        Number              55
S       Millisecond             Number              978
z       Time zone               General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z       Time zone               RFC 822 time zone   -0800
```

It's not exactly what you mean with "FMDAY", but I'll assume that you mean the text representation of day in week such as "Tuesday".

In that case, the desired `FMDAY, DD MONTH YYYY` format should be set as

```
<rich:calendar ... pattern="EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy" />
```

and `DD MON YYYY` as

```
<rich:calendar ... pattern="dd MMM yyyy" />
```

Today's date should then result in "Tuesday, 27 November 2012" and "27 Nov 2012" respectively.